# Rails Paperclip conflict between aws-s3 gem and right_aws gem. How to solve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, right-aws

for a new App I want to use paperclip to store Files to S3. I already have installed the aws-s3 gem for another app. That seems to cause some problems, because Paperclip should use right_aws but is trying to use the aws-s3 gem. But I don't want to remove the aws-s3 gem from my system. Is there a way to solve this conflict? Maybe by forcing paperclip to use right_aws? Or by changing the configuration?

**My setup**

```
# enviroment.rb
config.gem 'right_aws'

# my model with the attachment
has_attached_file :thumbnail, 
    :styles => { :thumb => "160x120>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazons3.yml",
    :path => ":provider/:attachment/:id_:style.:extension"

# config/amazons3.yml
development:
  bucket: bucketname
  access_key_id: secret
  secret_access_key: secret

test:
  bucket: bucketname
  access_key_id: secret
  secret_access_key: secret

production:
  bucket: bucketname
  access_key_id: secret
  secret_access_key: secret

# The Error in the console
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/right_http_connection-1.2.4/lib/net_fix.rb:85:in `send_request_with_body_stream'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/right_http_connection-1.2.4/lib/net_fix.rb:85:in `exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/right_http_connection-1.2.4/lib/net_fix.rb:144:in `request'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/connection.rb:45:in `request'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/connection.rb:52:in `request'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:69:in `request'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:88:in `put'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/object.rb:241:in `store'
...
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 12):

Wow, that was fast. I solved the issue by just using the aws-s3 gem and therefore changing my enviroment.rb to read:

```
#config.gem 'right_aws'
config.gem "aws-s3", :version => ">= 0.6.2", :lib => "aws/s3"
```

Hope that helps somebody!

Answer (score 4):

Not long ago Amazon released official [AWS SDK for Ruby](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby). It works pretty well with S3, supports American, European and Japanese S3 instances from the box and well maintained.

I have created a storage module for Paperclip called [paperclip-aws](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/paperclip-aws) to works with AWS SDK.

Feel free to use it. I hope that it will help.

Comment: Your module requires Paperclip, which seems to try to use aws-s3. How can I solve that?

Comment: Cristian, excuse me for so long answer. Paperclip requires `aws-s3` only for development, not for runtime. When you use `paperclip-aws` you just should include in into your Gemfile, like it is shown in documentation and then bundle. Nothing more is needed.

Comment: Great! Really pleased, that it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also. Specifying the gems in a certain order seems to work for some people:

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3", :version => '>= 0.6.2'
config.gem "paperclip", :version => '>= 2.3.1.1'
# config.gem "right_aws"
```

In my app I also had a plugin (backup_fu) specifying `right_aws` as well, and I had to comment out the line in my plugin as well:

```
# backup_fu.rb
require 'yaml'
require 'active_support'
require 'mime/types'
require 'right_aws' unless defined?(RightAws)
require 'erb'

class BackupFuConfigError < StandardError; end
class S3ConnectError < StandardError; end

class BackupFu
  # etc...
end
```

Does anyone know why this is an issue?

EDIT: In my app I no longer require right_aws at all, and then in the backup_fu gem I changed the require line to only require right_aws if it's not already loaded. I found that by requiring the gem in environment.rb, it caused a conflict with the aws-s3 gem. So now the backup_fu plugin will load it if required (usually only when running as a rake task), but not when the app is started up.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue here is that aws-s3 redefines a method called `send_request_with_body_stream`.

aws-s3's version has 4 arguments, and right_http_connection's has 5.  Depending on load order, aws-s3 can redefine right_http_connection's version of that method.

I cloned right_http_connection and made a quick fix for this issue.  I sent a pull request to right_http_connection.

Therefore you can use my git repo in your bundle to fix this issue:

`gem 'right_http_connection', :git => "git://github.com/gammons/right_http_connection"`